# How to get placeholder on input (text) to be valid in W3C validator?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Have this code in my HTML

```
<input name="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
<input name="Password" type="text" placeholder="Password"/>
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="login" />
```

It works fine when I run it but for my assignment to get good marks, I have to use W3C validator. Is there anyway I can bypass that or fix?

Comment: Which version of HTML do you use? What is the error you get in the validator?

Comment: @unor, not really sure but i use expression web 4. there just said the attributes placeholder not allow. if im not wrong its about XHTML 1.0 Transitional. sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use placeholder text as a replacement for a `label`, then no, there is no way around it and this is a good thing because placeholder text is not meant to replace a `label` but to act as a helpful guide.

Add a `label`.

Comment: but, does having label allow placeholder in the input text from W3C validator?

Comment: Yes of course, both are allowed, and can have different information. e.g. the label could say "username" and the placeholder might say "enter your username"

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use a `placeholder` attribute in XHTML 1.0.

The `placeholder` attribute [was introduced with (X)HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-html5-diff-20141209/#new-attributes). So if you want to use `placeholder`, you have to switch to (X)HTML5.

HTML5 document that contains your snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>

<input name="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
<input name="Password" type="text" placeholder="Password"/>
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="login" />
```

You can check it with https://validator.w3.org/nu/.